# How to read information about filtered data in datatable()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatable, datatables

I need to display Reset Filter only when the filter is in place. 
Need to read the filtered message. If the message contains "filtered", I would call the showResetFilter method. Tried table.info() but I get an error message "Object doesn't support property or method 'info'". Is there any other method that I may be able to use to read the filter message ? Image is linked here [TableImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZuTr.png).

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
var message =  table.info();
var isFiltered = message.indexOf("filtered") > -1;      

    if (isFiltered) { 
        ShowResetFilter();

    }
```

Comment: On my application with dataTables, the filtered message appears in a div with class "dataTables_info". Does yours have this as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two distinct ways you could do this, neither of which is very nice looking.

### Option 1

This is based on a previous version of DataTables, but it seems like it should still work. See [this forum post](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/17726) on the DataTables website, where someone asked a similar question. The author of the plugin said that the following was the only way to do it, but admitted that it was a bit of a workaround

**Edit:** It's been brought to my attention that my previous synax is incorrect. I had to guess at the capitalization when I took it out of hungarian notation. See the quotation below for the original syntax of this call, which *should* work in 1.10, but will be deprecated soon so I'd recommend against it.

My code was based on this quote from the author:

> Currently you need to do something like: `fnSettings().oPreviousSearch.sSearch` to get the current filter. I'll look at making that somewhat easier in 1.10.

But as far as I can tell, he didn't make it any easier in 1.10 :(

### Option 2

This is my method, which is about as ugly but should also work. You can try calling `page.info()` ([documentation here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.info())) to get the `recordsTotal` and `recordsDisplay` attributes. If they are equal, there is no filter, if they aren't, there must be a filter in place.  That would look something like this:

```
var pageInfo = table.page.info();
if(pageInfo.recordsTotal != pageInfo.recordsDisplay){
    //Handle it/do stuff 
}
```

Note that both of these methods are kinda hack-y, so if you're looking for the optimal solution, I'd recommend you keep looking.

Comment: I personally liked the  Option 2 and also reviewed the documentation but the recordsTotal and recordsDisplay is always 0  even when the Filter is on. Not sure what is going on.  I tested the Option 1, but I get this "Unable to get property 'search' of undefined or null reference" error.   Thank you for taking a time, I will try to make the Option 2 work

Comment: I changed option 1 from the notation you see in the quote, so I had to guess a bit at the capitalization. It might be previoussearch, or it could even be obsolete at this point. I'm not sure why you'd get 0 for those options, is your table loading and displaying correctly?

Comment: Filter information message is written before the data are loaded onto the table. This is why it is returning null or 0 for everything.  Not sure how to make data on the table load before it reads the message.  This method is already inside the  $(document).ready(function() .  Any ideas ?

Comment: @Everest I might be a little confused on exactly what you're filtering. Is this some external filter that you're applying outside of the normal dataTables search feature?

Comment: It is a dataTables. I created a callback function that is called after the data are loaded. It is working now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could read it from the div where it is updated directly:

```
var message = $(".dataTables_info").text();
```

Or, to be more specific in case you have multiple tables,

```
var message = $("#myTable_info").text();
```

And then use your original logic. Though, if you end up changing how this information will be displayed in the future, this will fall through, so I do think it is more in your interests to refactor a bit and use Chris H.'s Option 2